# How to append new line character in bash script if concatenating using +=?

Tags: bash

I am generating a data file using bash script. Cannot figure out how to append new line character..!

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=""
FILE="test.csv"

for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do
     DATA+="A,B\n"
done

echo $DATA >> $FILE
```

It prints

```
$ cat test.csv
A,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\nA,B\n
$ _
```

What I expect is:

```
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
A,B
```

It was done easliy when echoing directly to file, but for performance reason I started using += for concatenation to store information in var and push the bursts to file.

Cannot figure out how to concatenate new line character if using +=.

Apreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the option in your echo:

```
echo -e $DATA >> $FILE
```

`-e` enables echo to interpret backslash escapes.

Comment: Thanks. All the time I was trying to concatenate differently. WIthout realizing its about interpretation in echo :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to actually embed the result of formatting in the variable, there's a quote for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=""
FILE="test.csv"

for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do
     DATA+=$'A,B\n'
done

echo "$DATA" >> "$FILE"
```

The two changes are use of `$'fmt'` and quoting the argument to `echo`.

You could alternately use `printf` for more precise control.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATA=""
FILE="test.csv"

nl=""
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do
     printf -v DATA '%s%s%s' "$DATA" "$nl" "A,B"
     nl="\n"
done

echo "$DATA" >> "$FILE"
```

This uses the `$nl` variable to avoid the prepending `$DATA` with a newline.

One more variation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

FILE="test.csv"

nl=""
for ((i=1;i<=10;i++)) ; do
     printf '%s%s' "$nl" "A,B"
     nl="\n"
done >> "$FILE"
```

This avoids the intermediate variable `$DATA` by directing the output of the loop directly to `$FILE`. Note that you could apply this redirect directly to `printf` if you like. Redirecting the loop output MIGHT be a little faster because it only opens the file once, but the difference would likely be negligible.

Comment: This is a far better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: Rather than setting nl to different values in the loop, you can also do `unset a; nl=$'\n'; for i in 1 2 3; do a+="${a+$nl}A,B"; done`

Comment: If you're worried about perforrmance, why are you using bash?

Comment: @WilliamPursell, yes, the `${a+$nl}` idea works too, but is much much slower than setting `$nl` anew each time the loop runs. It seems that parameter expansion evaluations take a lot longer than simple reassignment. Try the benchmark on your own system: https://ideone.com/yM0XJG